# How to remove "More" button from liferay portlet toolbar

Tags: liferay, portlet, action-button

How to remove "More" button from liferay portlet toolbar.
I found an option to remove it from "portlet.vm" file but that will apply to all portlets (since its a template)
Looking for any other option.

Comment: You want to remove something, but not remove something? Please clarify

Comment: so you want to explicitly customize a specific portlet and you know which it is ? may be a fragment bundle is yours ?

Comment: You could also modify your theme css to just hide the button from UI

Comment: Hi All,
Thanks for your comments.
I want to remove "More" action button but only from a specific portlet.

Comment: @AndreAlbert
Actually there is no css specific to this project from which I need to hide portlet button but I will add a new css and try.
Thanks.

Comment: I have added a new css file containing the following in our project and it solved the problem.

.portlet-icon-menu {
 display: none ! important;
}